# Verification failure: CMS routines:cms_signerinfo_verify_cert:certificate verify error:..cms_smime.c:253:Verify error:self signed certificate

Tags: security, openssl, cryptography

1: Created private key and certificate by using following command

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private.key -out certificate.crt
```

2: Have simple text file to sign

```
$ cat message.txt
this is a test file.
```

3: Signed it with

```
 openssl cms -sign -in message.txt -text -out OutMessage.txt -inkey private.key -signer certificate.crt
```

4: for verification

```
openssl cms -verify -in OutMessage.txt -signer user.pem -out signedtext.txt
```

I am not sure why I am getting following error while verification step is performed, Please some one can help me out.

```
$ openssl cms -verify -in OutMessage.txt -signer  user.pem -out signedtext.txt
Verification failure
140539655524800:error:2E099064:CMS routines:cms_signerinfo_verify_cert:certificate verify 
error:../crypto/cms/cms_smime.c:253:Verify error:self signed certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error as you're using a self signed certificate, at least that's what the error is telling you. You can either add the certificate to your trust, or disable the certificate verify check when executing the command with the `-no_signer_cert_verify` option.

Comment: thanks for the reply but  this option ' no_signer_cert_verify  ' is not available. $ openssl cms -verify -no_signer_cert_verify -in OutMessage.txt
cms: Unrecognized flag no_signer_cert_verify

Comment: @Alok that's odd. Might be and older OpenSSL version you're running I suppose. Checkout here https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/cms.html